# About Truthiness and the Booleans True and False

Tags: python

My environment is : ubuntu 16.04  & python 2.7.12.

I read the documentation and found out that `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, and `None` are all considered `False` by default.

But I don't understand what's going on in the examples below:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=''
>>> a==False
False
>>> a==True
False
>>> a=bool(a)
>>> a==False
True
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> a="abcdefg"
>>> a==True
False
>>> a==False
False
>>> a=bool(a)
>>> a==True
True
>>>
```

I want get the right result and it appears I must use the `bool()` function to do so.
Is that correct and why?

Comment: All it means is that `[]` for example is automatically converted to `False` *when boolean conversion is needed*. You don't need to convert to a bool to assess a `==` statement thus, since `[]` and `False` are different objects, `[] == False` returns `False`. However `if []` will automatically be converted to `if False`.

Comment: Note that while the boolean converted value is used for if's and the like, the object will still retain its (non-boolean) value even after being evaluated to `True` or `False`. For instance, `[] and 42` returns `[]`, and `False or None` returns `None`. This is because boolean statements like these do not return `True` or `False`, but rather the value of the last expression evaluated before the value of the logical expression is known.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that those values *are equal to* `False`, it's that they *behave* as false when used in a boolean context.

It's certainly proper to cast to `bool` if you absolutely need a value of `True` or `False`, but in most cases it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) say:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use **in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations** below.

In other words, this works for `a = ''`:

```
if a:
    print "this won't print"
```

But `a` is still not *equal to* `False`.